# Is it bad to have a javascript timer constantly running (for session checking)?

Tags: javascript, session, timer

I am contemplating creating a 1 minute session logout warning message.

To do this, I assume I will need a javascript timer constantly running in the background.

Is this a terrible use of resources to run a timer constantly like this or is it small enough not to matter?

Comment: Running a timer every minute is not a problem (if the function it sets is not heavy nor leaking memory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a constantly running timer, you just need to use `setTimeout` set for 1 minute. If you idea is that this should be a inactivity timer, then all you need to do is clear it with `clearTimeout` and reset it when the user does something.

You could do something like:

```
var timerID;

function startTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        // Put your warning or auto logout here
    }, 60000);
}

function UserIsDoingSomething() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    // do something....
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. thats good Matt!  I set the server session timeout in a js variable when I first ajax to the server.  So I know that value.  Then I guess after every MOUSE STOP (??)  I could do the setTimeout with the time being SessionTimeout - 1minute.  At this point, show the warning!  Of course, reset on every mouse move.... Thats probably good enough to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: Might also want to consider more than mouse stop to support users who would only be using a keyboard or touch.

Comment: Actually, due to the client-side nature... I can keep track of NO movement easily but unless the users ajax back the server...they might still be getting logged out with no notice.  Fun!